# Parse and create message from config file/database/property file at run time

Tags: java

In my application perticular message structure/format are send and received. When I have to send the message, the message should be created on the particular format. I have parse message on perticular message. The message nothing but `byte array`

To parse the message I have used Preon lib.

I have following problem with :

1. Programatically I have to create the byte array for each field.
2. When message format get changed I have to change the code.

How can I construct run time message structure and parse the message structure.

The message structure look like this

```
Message1{

int field_1
char[2] field_2
long filed_3 
double filed_4
bit field_5
short field_6
char field_7

}


Message2{

    Message1 msg
    short field_8
    char field_9
}
```

1. Message structure will be change any time.
2. There are more than 1000 types of messages in the system.

So I am looking for solution in java which will create message  and parse from given structure runtime.

If you have  sample code, please provide the code sniipet.

Comment: If your message structure changes, but your code has not, how do you intended to handle the change?

Comment: Yes, somewhere in config file  or properties I will change like that.

Comment: How will changing the config file allow you to store data which you couldn't store before?

Comment: @Kamahire, When you accept an answer it means you gave a clear question and you worked with those answering the question until you got an answer which was acceptable. i.e. it is worth answering you questions. ;)

Comment: I can use database for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an OSGi container (karaf/iPOJO) which allows me to change the code while the application is running.  This means you can add fields, change their type and size while the system without bringing down the application.

Note: if you add a field or make a field larger but the code doesn't support it won't you lose information?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, OSGi address the different version of jar used in the application. It is generaly used to resolve the vesrion. I am sorry but I am not able to understand, how can I use OSGi. Can you give me sample code.

Comment: With an OSGi container you can load a new version of a library and remove the old version i.e. update all the code for message handling without stopping the application.